# Capacity of plain text file

Tags: file, caching

I have a plain text file with db file extension which I am using as a disk cache. I was wondering how much capacity a text file can have and how long it can grow? Is there a limit?

Comment: That depends on the file system you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plaintext file** limitations -

**On Windows**
Text files used by Notepad should be no larger than 45K. Notepad cannot open a file that exceeds 54 kilobytes (K) in size and does not allow you to continue editing a file if the file size reaches between 45K and 54K.

**On Linux**

Open the Terminal and then type the following command:
ulimit -a

You will see a lot of options, one of them being-

**file size               (blocks, -f) 5000**

This shows that the size is 5mb max.

You can also modify the limit in Linux.

Login as root and edit the file.

## vi /etc/security/limits.conf

Look for your username and fsize parameter. Delete this line or set new parameter. I am setting new file size limit to 2 GB.

bozzmob       hard  fsize  2048000

Logout and Login, so that the changes apply on your system.